# Почему x>y? Как компьютер определяет

Tags: javascript, теория

Если

```
let x = 5;
let y = 3;
```

Откуда компьютер знает что

```
x>y
```

Comment: Вычитанием. Если результат отрицательный (флаг знака результата установлен, см. SF в [Регистр флагов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80_%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2)), значит меньше, если положительный - значит больше.

Comment: Компьютер и не знает, он выполняет операции над памятью в своих регистрах, это больше описано в низкоуровневом языке ассемблер, подробнее про ассемблер можете почитать [тут](http://natalia.appmat.ru/c&c++/assembler.html)

Comment: Но для таких деталей лучше не js смотреть, а ассемблер. Можно "КОД" Петцольда почитать для ознакомления.

Answer (score -1):

Давайте сначала разберём, как человек сравнивает два натуральных числа. Сначала он определяет, где больше цифр. Это первый шаг сравнения. Если количество цифр одинаковое, то человек начинает попарно слева направо сравнивать эти цифры. Тогда, когда встретятся различные цифры, человек сразу определяет, какое число больше. При этом человек знает (помнит), что 9>8>7>6...

В компьютере реализован другой алгоритм. Как уже написали, ЦП вычитает из одного числа другое и сразу определяет знак результата и его равенство 0. Если результат получился больше нуля, то уменьшаемое больше вычитаемого, если 0 - то числа равны, если результат отрицательный, то уменьшаемое меньше вычитаемого. Такой агоритм подходит для сравнения любых вещественных чисел.

Comment: Столько слов, а полезной информации меньше чем в первом комментарии к вопросу...

Comment: Согласен с Андреем. Первый абзац как по мне вообще не нужен.